# How come that Sqrt(-4) is NaN and Sqrt(1/-4)=0?

Tags: c#, math

This gives me 0:

```
int B=-4;
double A = Math.Sqrt(1/B);
```

but this NaN

```
double A = Math.Sqrt(-4);
```

How is possible that the first calculation does not fail or at least does not return NaN as well as there is a square root of a negative number

EDIT: Thanks for the answers. I will add this one:

```
 int B=0;
 double A = 1/Math.Sqrt(B);
```

How come this is not the Zero divide exception?!

Comment: You're not getting an exception, because `double` can represent the result of diving by zero as `+Infinity`.

Comment: If you have a second question then **mark this question as answered and start a new question**. It makes it hard on the people trying to answer the question if more questions keep on appearing and it is not clear which ones have answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This here

```
int B=-4;
double A = Math.Sqrt(1/B);
```

is the same as

```
double A = Math.Sqrt(0);
```

because if you divide an integer by an integer you will get an integer

Answer (score 4):

Your first code is equivalent to:

```
int B = -4;
int C = 1 / B;
double A = Math.Sqrt(C);
```

Now do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(C);
```